# Proving that the sequence has a limit L using the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The Sequence $$\frac{3+5n^2}{n+n^2}$$ has a limit of 5, I can't seem to continue the solution in finding the value for N, below is my solution

if n > N, then $\lvert\frac{3+5n^2}{n+n^2}-5\rvert$ < $\epsilon$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $\lvert\frac{3+5n^2-5n^2-5n}{n+n^2}\rvert$ < $\epsilon$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $\lvert\frac{-5n+3}{n+n^2}\rvert$ < $\epsilon$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $\lvert-\frac{5n+3}{n+n^2}\rvert$ < $\epsilon$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $\frac{5n+3}{n+n^2}$ < $\epsilon$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $5n+3$ < $\epsilon(n+n^2)$

$\iff$ if n > N, then $3$ < $\epsilon n^2+\epsilon n-5n$

???

Comment: You have an error in your work which may be causing this issue. Notice that $\frac{-5n+3}{n+n^2} \neq - \frac{5n+3}{n+n^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{-5n+3}{n+n^2}\ne-\frac{5n+3}{n+n^2}.$

For any $n\in\mathbb N^*$, $\left|\frac{3+5n^2}{n+n^2}-5\right|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow5n-3<\epsilon(n^2+n).$

A sufficient condition is $5n<\epsilon n^2$, i.e. $n>\frac5\epsilon$, so any $N\ge\frac5\epsilon$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

For $n> N$ we need that

$$\left\lvert \frac{3+5n^2}{n+n^2}-5\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{3+5n^2-5n-5n^2}{n+n^2}\right\rvert= \left\lvert\frac{5n-3}{n+n^2}\right\rvert < \frac{5(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=\frac{5}{n} < \epsilon$$ so we can pick $N>\frac{5}{\epsilon}$

Credit to @AnneBauvalfor spotting error in your calculations

Comment: where did you get the $$\frac{5(n+1)}{n(n+1)}$$

Comment: The solution that I know is computing the inequality in terms of epsilon, then taking the value of N

Comment: @Benny $5n+3<5n+5=5(n+1)$, so $\frac{5n+3}{n^2+n}<\frac{5(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=\frac{5}{n}$

Comment: @Benny: I added two to the numerator which made the fraction larger. It's OK because if larger fraction is less than epsilon then our original fraction will also be less than epsilon.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I see now